# jQuery : Event not binding in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-10

I want to attach a double click event on an ID/Element if there is a single left click on that same ID/Element.

for Ex my code is

```
if($("#file_upload").length > 0)
{
    $("#file_upload").on('mousedown', function() {
        $("#file_upload").dblclick(); //This thing not working in IE 10
    });             
}
```

this issue is while using `jQuery.fileUpload.`
jQuery version is 1.8.2

also i m binding event on `mousedown` so it might get triggered on right click but i want event binding only on left click

Comment: Do you want to attach an event handler for a double click or trigger a double click event?

Comment: triggering dblclick is the same `$('#file_upload').trigger('dblclick');`

Comment: actually thing is single click has some issue in IE 10 whn using jQuery.fileUpload .. and it works on dble click .. so m tryin to trigger the dble click when theres a single left click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not telling the code what to do when the double click occurs.

Just as other events, the code should be told what to do when it occurs..

```
  if($("#file_upload").length > 0)
  {
    $("#file_upload").on('mousedown', function() {
        $("#file_upload").dblclick(function () {
            alert("Double click!");
        });
     });                
  }
```

Next to this, i'm wondering it it'll work.. it's expecting to have a mouse down and seeing a double click occur.. when releasing the mouse button for a double click, i assume it'll leave the mousedown event, and the double click event won't be fired.

Might require some testing in this case.